# Why g++ wont compile simple code?

Tags: c++, g++

I got strange error why compiling a simple source code in g++:

```
#include <vector>
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler output is

```
g++ -c -Wall main.cpp
main.cpp:4:20: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};
                      ^
                      ;
1 error generated.
```

When I compile it in xCode everything works fine.

Comment: Which version of g++?, please give us something reproducible. Post a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nonetheless, try adding `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` to your compiler flag

Comment: It's likely you aren't compiling with C++11 or higher

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11? Try adding `-std=c++11` to your compilation flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your compiler command to

```
> g++ -std=c++11 -c -Wall main.cpp
> #   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

if your GCC compiler version doesn't support that flag you should upgrade to a newer version (which probably supports the current standard by default).

Comment: Apparently the advice in comments adding the flag -std=gnu++11 solve the problem. I was confused since -std=gnu++14 should be the default flag but it seems I have old version of g++.
Thanks for advices.